# How do I include CodeIgniter within a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, plugins

I have a WordPress website. I am writing a plugin for WordPress where I want to use the CodeIgniter framework within the plugin. I am having trouble with this because the CodeIgniter bootstrap file "index.php" expects to be run in the global scope, not within a function.

```
Right now, within my plugin, I do the following:
// BEGIN: plugin code
function classifieds_template_redirect()
{
  global $wp;
  $plugin_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
  if (preg_match('/^CI/', $wp->request))  // Use CodeIgniter to handle the request
  {
    include($plugin_path."/index.php";  // Include the CodeIgniter bootstrap file
    die();
  }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'classifieds_template_redirect' );
// END: plugin code
```

The following error is being throw:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/site.utils/htdocs/CodeIgniter/system/core/Utf8.php on line 47

I believe this is due to CodeIgniter expecting its bootstrap index.php file to be run in global scope.

Any ideas?

Comment: What parts of codeigniter do you want to use for this wordpress plugin? This seems way overly complicated.

Comment: I want to use the url feature in codeigniter which will automaticly call the controller/method based on the url ... and this will be contained within a wordpress plugin.

Comment: I dunno, sounds like you're trying to fit a round peg in a square hole to me.

Comment: Doesn't Wordpress already have built-in routing?

Comment: i agree with gclaghorn. you sound like want to reinventing the wheel.

Comment: well, its really the MVC framework that I want to take advantage of. I have whole portions of websites which need to be self contained with in a plugin so that I can reuse it on other websites. I thought of using codeigniter because its a widely used MVC framework and thus other programmers who get hired at my company would easily learn the software if they already know codeigniter. I may just develop a lighter subset of codeigniter for this project but before I do that, I would like to see if we can  get this idea working.

Answer (score 2):

Here are your options:

1. Rewrite URLs (using your webserver) which starts with a certain identifier to get sent to CodeIgniter's bootstrap
2. Rewrite CodeIgniter's routing boiler plate to adjust to not being run through bootstrap over global scope
3. Use a small [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) plugin in WordPress instead of CodeIgniter

I am going to cover the first one, because I think that it makes the most sense if you are going to be stubborn about sticking with CodeIgniter. And I am going to give you some proof of concept code using Apache as the webserver and mod_rewrite to accomplish this.

Basically all we will achieve is your code you have shown us, but instead we will make Apache do it for us, making CodeIgniter being run though its bootstrap over global scope.

All you do is to add more rules to the WordPress `.htaccess`-file. Like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Here's the code which rewrites the URL to your CodeIgniter plugin.
        RewriteRule ^CI/(?.*)$ wp-content/plugins/ci-plugin/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Now all request to `www.example.com/CI/...` will be passed to CodeIgniter's bootstrap over global scope.

Comment: The mod-rewrite solution mentioned above does not solve the solve the problem. This doesn't include codeigniter within the wordpress context. Doing the mod-rewrite solution is just as if I was not running wordpress at all. The solution I am looking for is one where I can be within wordpress and have codeigniter be my plugin framework.

Comment: Why did you show us code saying that you wanted this exact thing then? You need to explain better. Do you want to use wordpress theme engine and then have plugin functions run in the theme? And then use plugin to generate the output of the plugin functions?